# Date field comparison in linq DataService Query

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service to fetch the customer records from a table which has Datetime column as well. In my UI I have a grid which displays Name and DOB.I have a text box for filter. When there is a text entered in the filter, I want that text to be compared against all the columns in the table. I am getting an exception when the search text is compared against the Datetime column. This is the query am using below.

```
enter code here
db.Customers.Where(customer => customer.LastName.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
                               customer.FirstNme.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
                               (customer.DOB.Value.Year.ToString()
                                                       .StartsWith(text)
                  );
```

This throws an exception 'Error translating the linq expression to URI'.

On the other hand if I just compare the Datetime field with a direct value it works.

```
enter code here

db.Customers.Where(customer => customer.LastName.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
                   customer.FirstNme.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
                   (customer.DOB.Value.Year == 1985)
                  );
```

How can I compare my Datetime column with the entered text??

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your entered text to an integer and replace the literal in your second query with it:

```
int year;
if(!int.TryParse(text, out year)) year = -1;
var res = db.Customers.Where(customer => 
    customer.LastName.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
    customer.FirstNme.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
    (customer.DOB.Value.Year == year)
);
```

By setting `year = -1` in the case of the data not being numeric, that guarantees that nothing in that particular date field will match.

Of course, this assumes that you're just interested in comparing against the Year property. If you needed to compare the full datetimes, you could parse your entered text as a DateTime, then use that for comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess this will work. But incase if i want to compare the date and month too, I think I have to do more parsing with the input text since its free flow text. Is there any way I can get the Datetime field as a string which will be more easy for my comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a specific reason for doing things in the order you are trying to, but I would try to convert your string to a date time, rather than trying to convert your date time into a string.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(string);
```

then you can compare with:

```
db.Customers.Where(customer => customer.LastName.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
                           customer.FirstNme.ToUpper().StartsWith(text) ||
                           (customer.DOB.Value.Year == dt.Year

              );
```